# Share google sheet with appscript attached without sharing the code

Tags: google-apps-script

So my goal is to share a google sheet that has an appscript attached to it without sharing the code of the actual appscript.
Ideally i would like to have like n numbers of copies of my google sheet and only one appscript so if I update my appscript it automatically gets updated on all sheets but i dont want it that anyone can actually see the code.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you'll have to make an add-on to hide the code completely.

There is another way, much easier to make, user will be able to see your code but they would have to be experienced in google-apps-script ;-)

> n numbers of copies of my google sheet and only one appscript so if I
> update my appscript it automatically gets updated

For this goal you probably should use the [Library](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries#create_and_share_a_library). That way you will have a single code/project with several public functions.
Then each of the N sheets will have an apps-script attached that calls that library.

That way google-apps-script project contained in the Google Sheets file will be super simple, just some calls to the library. You can't make it invisible to the users but once they open it they won't see the implementation, only the calls.

However, you will have to share your library to all the end-users in minimal (view-only) mode. In order to use the solution, users will have to have the view access. When sharing the library project - do not choose to notify them by email. But, if they know how to do it - they could open the Library project too, in view-only mode and see your Library code.

If you choose to go with the library solution, there are some details with the library versions. You may change the library in the future.

If you do a breaking changes (public functions, add/delete/rename/change parameters) - you will have to change the code in each sheets-contained google-apps-script project. That scenario is clear.

If you do a non-breaking changes (public function signatures stay the same) that just improve/change your inner implementation then sheets-contained google-apps-script project can choose to connect to the Library:

- a) developer mode (live)
- b) specific version

Each choice is a trade off:

- a) is much risky if you make a coding error but you have to do nothing to update the N files
- b) is more safe, but once you finish coding and testing you'll have to go to each file and increment the used library version manually.

Comment: Thanks for that detailed information. I tried it with the library but like you mentioned my users are still able to access my code via the shared with me section.